# SwiftUI on Xcode Playground vs Swift Playground - different outputs

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm running this code on Xcode Playground and Swift Playground:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                Text("hello World")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Anybody knows why we get so different outputs from the same code?

[image: Swift Playground results]

[image: Xcode Playground results]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the iPad, you are running in Dark Mode, and that is making the default background of the view black.  Also, the iPad Swift Playgrounds provides a frame in which the view runs.  This frame varies if you switch between portrait and landscape mode, but in either case it is providing a frame in which to draw.

In Playgrounds in Xcode, the view is just taking up a minimum of size.

You can get a similar look in Xcode by providing a `.frame` and using a `Color.black` background:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                Text("hello World")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 600)
        .background(Color.black)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: You can also set a [`previewDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/previewdisplayname(_:)), https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/previews-different-states/ instead of a frame.